# Angular // innerHTML data binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to set up a dynamic table, one of the cell of the table need to be populated with a progress bar. I was trying an innerHTML solution for that but does not works. Any suggestions?

Here my dahsboard.component.html code, the camp not working is that **[innerHTML]="tableRow.limitOccupancy"**:

```
<div class="divTableRow" *ngFor="let tableRow of tableRows">
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.name }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.value }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.previousValue }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.delta }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.rafLimit }}</div>
   <div [innerHTML]="tableRow.limitOccupancy" class="divTableCell"></div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.date }}</div>
</div>
```

and here my dashboard.component.ts, the intention is that **limitOccupancy will get the progressBar template that will be transfered using innerHTML**:

```
progressBar = '<div class="progress-bar"><span></span></div>';

tableRows = [
    {
        name: 'LEVEL 3',
        value: '8%',
        previousValue: '7%',
        delta: '-11000',
        rafLimit: '12%',
        limitOccupancy: this.progressBar,
        date: '12.09.20',

    },
    {
        name: 'LEVEL 1',
        value: '8%',
        previousValue: '7%',
        delta: '-11000',
        rafLimit: '12%',
        limitOccupancy: this.progressBar,
        date: '12.09.20',
    },
    
];
```

Comment: hat sould work. what exactly is happening?

Comment: Nothing. cell will remain empty :(

Comment: On inspect i can see the progress bar, but is not visualizable

Comment: might be a problem with the style. keep in mind that angular removes everything from component style that it does not see as being referenced in the template, so you may need `::ng-deep` for the style classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issues. I can see div is loading and added class in style.css. its adding css as well. Please let me know what's the issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1dsmxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would prefer the creation of a custom "progress-bar" component.

```
export class ProgressBarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() progress: number = 0;

  ngOnInit() {}

  clampProgress() {
    return Math.max(
      Math.min(this.progress, Math.max(0, 100)),
      Math.min(0, 100)
    );
  }
}
```

```
<div class="light-grey">
  <div class="grey" style="height:24px" [ngStyle]="{width:progress+'%'}"></div>
</div>
```

```
.light-grey {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

And then using it in a way like this:

```
<div class="divTableRow" *ngFor="let tableRow of tableRows; let index as i">
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.name }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.value }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.previousValue }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.delta }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.rafLimit }}</div>
   <div class="divTableCell">
       <app-progress-bar [progress]="getLimitOccupancy(i)"></app-progress-bar>
   </div>
   <div class="divTableCell">{{ tableRow.date }}</div>
</div>
```

where `getLimitOccupancy(index)` is now just a function that returns a number from 0 to 100 giving the row-item identifier as a parameter.

here a live example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r8wjag?file=src/app/app.component.ts